# Where was A.L.I.E uploaded?

Tags: the-100

When the fight between the *Skaikru/ Sky People* people from *Arkadia/ The Ark* against the people chipped by the first *A.L.I.E* gets tighter, there's the attempt to save the program. Where exactly tries *A.L.I.E* to find a safe harbor?

To not spoiler anyone, the full question is hidden below … please **do not** hover over the yellow box until you have seen season 1-3 until episode 14.

> When *John Murphy*, *Charles Pike* and *Indra* lock themselves up in the holy room, they try to disconnect the backpack containing the *A.L.I.E* server from the nuclear battery to destroy it. This process gives the A.I. time to upload herself to the landing pot. Moments later she is seen in a circular space station looking like *The Ark*. Is this just her own "imagination", her own "City of Light", so the original landing pot takes this form in her mind to express how save she feels there? Or does this space station really exists and therefore she is save from everyone who has no orbital nuke at hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [The 100 wikia entry about the Ark](http://the100.wikia.com/wiki/The_Ark)

> Season Three:
>
> The Ark is viewed again in episode ["Red Sky at Morning"](http://the100.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Sky_at_Morning). **A.L.I.E. is transferred to the mainframe in the Go-Sci Ring, the only Ark station left in space.**

So yes, it is real, and she is safe from ground attacks.  I suppose they would have to figure out a way to hack the mainframe remotely, or repair a dropship/pod, to reach her.

Comment: Completely forgot that Jaha was left at the Go-Sci Ring. Thanks a lot!